# Get R data frame in Python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to use Python and R together with **rpy2**

I want to get live covid 19 data, so I chose to go with the **covid19.analytics** R package

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')
r_covid19 = 'covid19.analytics'#live covid 19 data package
#utils.install_packages((r_covid19), repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')
importr(r_covid19)

#R function to get daily cov 19 reports: 
#Works fine in R
#covid19_data = covid19.data(case = "aggregated", local.data = FALSE, debrief = FALSE)

#code to get covid 19 data 
cv19_df = r[r_covid19].covid19.data('case = "aggregated", local.data = FALSE, debrief = FALSE')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pinkeye\Desktop\RESEARCH\py code\practice_pandas.py", line 61, in <module>
    print(r[r_covid19])
  File "C:\Users\pinkeye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 396, in __getitem__
    res = _globalenv.find(item)
  File "C:\Users\pinkeye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\conversion.py", line 44, in _
    cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pinkeye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\_rinterface_capi.py", line 282, in _
    robj = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pinkeye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\sexp.py", line 338, in find
    raise KeyError("'%s' not found" % key)
KeyError: "'covid19.analytics' not found"
```

I know very basic R so please help me solve this problem

Comment: Note that when you use `rpy2` many of the dots are translated into underscores so as to not conflict with the way python names things. Does `r["covid19_analytics"].covid19_data(...)` work? or give a different error message? Or maybe use `covid = importr(r_covid19)` then `covid.covid19_data(...)`

Comment: @MrFlick the program progressed a little!
changing the ```importr``` statement helped move past the KeyError I got
I am now getting a runtime error:
```File "C:\Users\pinkeye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface.py", line 624, in __call__
    raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in covid19.JHU.data(case, local.data, debrief) : 
  Unrecognized selection of case <case=aggregated, local.data=FALSE, debrief=FALSE> -- possible options are: aggregated ts-confirmed ts-deaths(... etc)```

Comment: Actually I just noticed you seem to have quotes around the entire parameter list. That doesn't seem right. It should look like `covid.covid19_data(case = "aggregated", local.data = False, debrief = False)` well, actually, there's another dot problem. so maybe instead: `covid.covid19_data(**{"case": "aggregated", "local.data" : False, "debrief": False})`